# When all countries are not following daylight saving in timezone

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In Atlantic standard time some countries follow daylight savings while some doesn't follow. In Sql server 2016 there is system table **sys.time_zone_info** which shows  Dayllight saving is true in "Atlantic Standard Time".

My question is what should do if all countries don't follow the daylight saving in that time zone?

Comment: Most likely, in those countries that don't follow the daylight savings the time zone is called something differently, not "Atlantic Standard Time".  Besides, the rules for each time zone may change from year to year, so I would not rely much on what is built into SQL Server.

Comment: By changing rules I mean... For example, did you know that Perth in Australia was observing the daylight savings for few years from 2006 to 2009 as an experiment and don't observe it now? In this sense it would be unwise to rely on a static list of time zones rules.

Comment: And even if it was updated it is not always accurate, at least in the US. Look at Indiana and Arizona. But your question is too vague. How could anybody what you should do? Do with what? You need to explain what it is you trying to solve.